# Updating rows in a specific column in a csv file (Python)

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am currently working on a very large CSV file. I only want to update the blank rows in the first column. I want to loop through each row and update each row (in column 1) with the value of the previous column.

FOR EXAMPLE: As you can see in the first column, the first row (excluding the header) is `migrations`, I want the 2 blank rows below to display `migrations` too. Then there is `oauth_token_scopes`, I want the blank rows after it to be populated with `oauth_token_scopes`. If this is possible, I would really appreciate the help!

[CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uA0W.png)

Comment: So are you looking for help with reading and writing a csv, or the algorithm requred to populate a matrix as specified? In order to the answer as generally usefull as possible for others, please make it clear where you are stuck :)

Comment: @RasmusDamgaardNielsen Thank you for your quick response. It would be the reading and writing to the csv I would need help with! Alongside the execution of the loop, where I am populating the column? Apologies if this response doesn't make things much clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can import the csv into a pandas dataframe using `pd.read_csv(filename)` and then use pandas `fillna`. Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TableNames": ["migrations", None, None, "oauth_access_token_scopes", None, None, None],
                   "HeaderNames": [None, "migration", "batch", None, "id", "access_token_id", "scope_id"],
                  })
df["TableNames"] = df["TableNames"].fillna(method="ffill")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read the CSV into a 2D list in Python. Then loop through the column you want to edit and store in memory the value of the last filled-in cell, pasting this value into all blank rows until you reach a new cell with a value.

Something like this:

```
csv_list = [["Stuff", "  ", "", "", "Other Stuff", "", "", "Final"], ["whatever", "x", 
"    ", "   ", "", "     ", "", ""]] # Here we are assuming that columns are the primary index
print("List before filling in blanks: ", csv_list)
prev_val = csv_list[0][0] # Assume first cell is not blank
for i in range(len(csv_list[0]) - 1): # Loop through first column
    if csv_list[0][i].strip() == "": # Check if cell is empty
        csv_list[0][i] = prev_val # Fill in cell if empty
    else:
        prev_val = csv_list[0][i] # Set new prev_val if cell is not empty
print("After: ", csv_list)
```

Which prints:

```
List before filling in blanks:  [['Stuff', '  ', '', '', 'Other Stuff', '', '', 'Final'],
                                 ['whatever', 'x', '    ', '   ', '', '     ', '', '']]
After:  [['Stuff', 'Stuff', 'Stuff', 'Stuff', 'Other Stuff', 'Other Stuff', 'Other Stuff', 'Final'], 
         ['whatever', 'x', '    ', '   ', '', '     ', '', '']]
```

Comment: Hi Bob, this looks great! Is there any advice on structuring my csv file into a 2D list?

Comment: this looks great! Is there any advice on structuring my csv file into a 2D list?